# Trying to run statments on pig getting error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

When i start to read a file on hdfs using pig in mapreduce mode, when i used dump b it started the mapreduce process and after completing it, it goes on to repetition please tell me whats the problem. (I have set the file permissions to 777 and /tmp permissions in hdfs to 777).

```
[root@master conf]# pig -x mapreduce
17/04/19 23:05:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
17/04/19 23:05:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
17/04/19 23:05:59 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2017-04-19 23:05:59,615 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530) compiled Jun 01 2016, 23:10:49
2017-04-19 23:05:59,615 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /opt/hadoop/pig/conf/pig_1492623359614.log
2017-04-19 23:05:59,652 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /root/.pigbootup not found
2017-04-19 23:06:01,031 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost/
2017-04-19 23:06:02,136 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost:8021
2017-04-19 23:06:02,205 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Pig Script ID for the session: PIG-default-3df7c96f-9eac-4874-aab9-9ca7726fe860
2017-04-19 23:06:02,205 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - ATS is disabled since yarn.timeline-service.enabled set to false
grunt> a= load '/temp' AS (name:chararray, age:int, salary:int);
grunt> b= foreach a generate (name, salary);
grunt> dump b;
2017-04-19 23:06:22,093 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2017-04-19 23:06:22,190 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2017-04-19 23:06:22,267 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2017-04-19 23:06:22,309 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor - Columns pruned for a: $1
2017-04-19 23:06:22,456 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (Tenured Gen) of size 699072512 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489350752, usageThreshold = 489350752
2017-04-19 23:06:22,564 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2017-04-19 23:06:22,589 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2017-04-19 23:06:22,589 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2017-04-19 23:06:22,724 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2017-04-19 23:06:23,128 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2017-04-19 23:06:23,152 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2017-04-19 23:06:23,154 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2017-04-19 23:06:23,820 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/opt/hadoop/pig/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2091099620/tmp-1166978625/pig-0.16.0-core-h2.jar
2017-04-19 23:06:23,951 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/opt/hadoop/pig/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2091099620/tmp-1829507825/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2017-04-19 23:06:24,026 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/opt/hadoop/pig/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2091099620/tmp-1436552250/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2017-04-19 23:06:24,119 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/opt/hadoop/pig/lib/joda-time-2.9.3.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp2091099620/tmp-1393102603/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2017-04-19 23:06:24,132 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2017-04-19 23:06:24,148 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2017-04-19 23:06:24,148 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2017-04-19 23:06:24,148 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2017-04-19 23:06:24,279 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2017-04-19 23:06:24,302 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2017-04-19 23:06:24,920 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-04-19 23:06:24,952 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2017-04-19 23:06:24,995 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-04-19 23:06:24,995 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-04-19 23:06:25,056 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2017-04-19 23:06:25,375 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:1
2017-04-19 23:06:25,889 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_1492621692528_0002
2017-04-19 23:06:26,195 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner - Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
2017-04-19 23:06:26,411 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted application application_1492621692528_0002
2017-04-19 23:06:26,537 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1492621692528_0002/
2017-04-19 23:06:26,537 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1492621692528_0002
2017-04-19 23:06:26,537 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases a,b
2017-04-19 23:06:26,537 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: a[1,3],b[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2017-04-19 23:06:26,595 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2017-04-19 23:06:26,595 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1492621692528_0002]
2017-04-19 23:06:48,598 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complete
2017-04-19 23:06:48,598 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1492621692528_0002]
2017-04-19 23:06:51,639 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2017-04-19 23:06:51,705 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2017-04-19 23:06:52,983 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:06:53,985 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:06:54,989 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:06:55,993 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:06:56,994 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:06:57,995 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:06:58,999 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:07:00,001 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2017-04-19 23:07:01,005 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

[2]+  Stopped                 pig -x mapreduce
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the `JobHistoryServer`

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

Pig when ran in mapreduce mode expects the **JobHistoryServer** to be available.

Comment: Your thing worked but when am executing pig staments its giving me same result all the time

Comment: What do yo mean by *same result*, Please explain?

Comment: cant add the whole text here how do I share??
man for instance if I am doing like  data = load '/temp' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray, age:int, salary:int);
and then  b = foreach data generate name,age;
then its giving me (anmol     25     1000000,)
(dev       39     4000000,)
(ron       21     10003,)
(sam       39     1451124,)
and if i do b = foreach data generate name; then again it gives me
anmol     25     1000000,)
(dev       39     4000000,)
(ron       21     10003,)
(sam       39     1451124,)

Comment: If the issue is different from the post here, Please open a new post with all the details.

Comment: ok am opening a new ticket I cant mark the answer because i dont have enough repeutation to mark

Comment: To accept the answer, there is no reputation level. Try clicking the tick mark. You need 15 reputation to upvote. Upvote and accept are two different things.